# How to create Nested array of json objects below using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my custom json structure how can i create this using javascript

var heading = "someValue";

creating below json structure appending heading  value getting problem

```
{
    "check": {
        heading : [{
            "CheckName": "CheckJSON"
        }, {
            "CheckName": "checkJson121"
        }],
        heading : [{
            "CheckName": "CheckJSON"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: That's invalid JSON markup

Comment: In this case you have duplicate key "heading"

Comment: Please re-read your question yourself and see if it really makes any sense to you because it does not to me.

Comment: If you use JSON please validate it before: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ your JSON is, as stated above not valid. And this is just one reason you are "getting problem".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var heading = "someValue";

var data = {
    "check": {
        [heading] : [{
            "CheckName": "CheckJSON"
        }, {
            "CheckName": "checkJson121"
        }],
        [heading] : [{
            "CheckName": "CheckJSON"
        }]
    }
}

console.log('data:', data);
// In JSON format
console.log('json:', JSON.stringify(data));
```